# toggle only one specific panel within a ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello I want to toggle one specific panel but if I click on the button the panels of other objects will be opened. How can I just open the clicked panel?

**toggle.component.ts**

```
 opened:Boolean=false;
 toggle () {

    this.opened = !this.opened;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main" *ngFor="let x of data; let i=index;">
<footer>

  <div class="icons">
  <span id="{{item.id}}" (click)="toggle()">6<i class="fa fa-users {{i}}" ></i></span>
  <span >6<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></span>
  <span >6<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i></span>
  <div class="iconsRight pull-right">
  <span >EXIF<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span>
  <span ><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
  <span ><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i></span>
  </div>
  </div>

</footer>

<div class="togglePanel{{item.id}}" *ngIf="opened" >
  <hr/>
  <ul class="toggleWrapper">
    <li>YES</li>
    <hr/>
    <li>YES</li>
    <hr/>
    <li>YES</li>
    <hr/>
    <li>YES</li>

  </ul>
</div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save state of individual panel. Currently you just set one variable which toggles all the panels.

In your `toggle.component.ts`, add a variable to store every item's state:

```
togglePanel: any = {};
```

Then, change your html to following:

```
<div class="main" *ngFor="let x of data; let i=index;">
    <footer>
        <div class="commentAgent">Text des Bewerters, der die Bearbeitung dieses Bildes vorgenommen hat</div>
        <div class="icons">
            <span id="{{item.id}}" (click)="togglePanel[i] = !togglePanel[i]">6<i class="fa fa-users {{i}}" ></i></span>
            <span>6<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></span>
            <span>6<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i></span>
            <div class="iconsRight pull-right">
                <span>EXIF<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>/span>
                <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                <span><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div class="togglePanel{{item.id}}" *ngIf="togglePanel[i]">
        <hr/>
        <ul class="toggleWrapper">
            <li>YES</li>
            <hr/>
            <li>YES</li>
            <hr/>
            <li>YES</li>
            <hr/>
            <li>YES</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you don't need the `toggle()` method and the variable `opened` in this approach.

Comment: ok fine but see image above please. The panels on the right sight is also opened. Without content

Comment: what changes have you made ?

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake. I had an wrapper div around the staff

Comment: But can you tell me why togglePanel[i] is a boolean value?

Comment: because it stores the Open/Close state, we use a boolean for that.

Comment: This is the easiest way of binding. Thanks for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one panel opened, then this method will work. Instead on setting your 'flag' property boolean, use number. It will keep the panel id. Set it to the panel id and you don't need an additional property on your data:

**Typescript:**

```
opened = -1;
toggle (index) {

    this.opened = index;
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
....
  <span id="{{item.id}}" (click)="toggle(item.id)">6<i class="fa fa-users {{i}}" ></i>
...

<div class="togglePanel{{item.id}}" *ngIf="opened===item.id" >
```

Comment: Also it would be better to use a service to manage the states of your panels for a lot of reasons.
Mostly, it's better if another component needs to toggle the state.

Comment: this works well if the user wants only one panel to be opened. From OP's question I understand that toggle of each individual panel is required, something like expansion panel, not accordion

Comment: @Faisal, true, but I read : ' I want to toggle one specific panel '

Comment: yeah, thats right - but one specific can be any panel in my opinion. Maybe the OP can clarify the requirement, +1 for the solution though.